# React make class active on element click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to make class active on when box is clicked using React hooks.

The box is not a simple div element, but is dynamically loaded from an array.

I have problem with this funtion:

```
const changeClassName = (props) => {
  return props.className.replace("box active");
};
```

This doesn't change the `className` property.

Full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1"
const sounds = [
    {
      key: "A",
      mp3: "https://audiodeploy.netlify.app/8%20El-Mu'minun,%20115-116.mp3",
    },
    {
        key: "B",
        mp3: "https://audiodeploy.netlify.app/8%20El-Mu'minun,%20115-116.mp3",
      }
  ];
  
  const App = () => {
    const [keys, setKeys] = useState([
      "1","2"
    ]);
    const [active, setActive]=useState(false);
    return (
      <>
        <span id="text"></span>
        <div id="display" className="display">
          {sounds.map((sound, id) => {
            return <Box text={sound.key} audio={sound.mp3} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };
  const changeClassName=(props)=>{
    return(
       props.className.replace("box active") // this doesn't change the className
    )
  }
  const playSound = (audioRef,props) => {
    audioRef.current.play();
    console.log(props.text);
    if(props.text==='A'||props.text=='B')
    ReactDOM.render(
      <>
   <p> Then did you think that We created you uselessly and that to Us you would not be returned?"</p>
   <p>So exalted is Allāh, the Sovereign, the Truth; there is no deity except Him, Lord of the Noble Throne.</p>
   <p>[Quran, 23:115-116]</p>
      </>
      , document.getElementById('text'));
      changeClassName(props);
  };
  
  const Box = (props) => {
    const audioRef = React.useRef();
  
    return (
      <div className="box" onClick={() => playSound(audioRef,props)}>
        {props.text}
        <audio
          src={props.audio}
          ref={audioRef}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Could you please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work for the active part, but you may need to clean that up a little bit

https://codepen.io/quentinbenyahia/pen/yLqaEvv

```
const App = () => {

      const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
const playSound = (audioRef,id) => {
    audioRef.current.play();
    ReactDOM.render(
      <>
   <p> Then did you think that We created you uselessly and that to Us you would not be returned?"</p>
   <p>So exalted is Allāh, the Sovereign, the Truth; there is no deity except Him, Lord of the Noble Throne.</p>
   <p>[Quran, 23:115-116]</p>
      </>
      , document.getElementById('text'));
  setIsActive(id)
  };
    
    return (
      <>
        <span id="text"></span>
        <div id="display" className="display">
          {sounds.map((sound, id) => {
            return <Box playSound={(audioRef) => { playSound(audioRef, id ) }} isActive={id === isActive} text={sound.key} audio={sound.mp3} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };
 
  
  
  const Box = (props) => {
    const audioRef = React.useRef();
    return (
      <div  className={props.isActive ? "box active": "box"} onClick={() => props.playSound(audioRef)}>
        {props.text}
        <audio
          src={props.audio}
          ref={audioRef}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can follow these steps:

```
1- const [isActive , setIsActive] = useState(false)
2- const changeClassName=(props)=>{
     setIsActive(true)
  }
3- <div className={isActive ? "box active": "box"} onClick={() => playSound(audioRef,props)}>
        {props.text}
        <audio
          src={props.audio}
          ref={audioRef}
        />
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks, I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: do you have a GitHub repo?

Comment: I don't have yet, I just need this fix and after that fix I will upload the whole project to github inshallah, could you please fix this in my codepen may Allah reward you

Comment: I'm trying but nothing is displayed on my screen

Comment: jazakallahu khairan for your effort. someone posted answer if you are interested